# translation mysql_fetch_array to PDO::FETCH_NUM

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the equivalent of these two code in PDO

first:

```
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

second:

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $data[]=$row;
 }
```

i used these codes below but they are not exact same i guess, because the rest of the code didn't work.

```
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

and

```
 $data[] = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are the correspondences:

- `mysql_fetch_array` = `fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)` - The rows are arrays with both numeric and named indexes.
- `mysql_fetch_assoc` = `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` - The rows are arrays with named indexes.
- `mysql_fetch_row` = `fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` - The rows are arrays with numeric indexes.
- `mysql_fetch_object` = `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` or `fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS)` depending on whether you specify the optional `className` argument to `mysql_fetch_object`. The rows are objects, either of the specified class or `stdClass`.

The `while` loop is equivalent to:

```
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the data of the query in an array with this:

```
$data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

If that's not working, your PDO connection is probably not setup right or your query didn't run. You can try troubleshooting the query with something like this:

```
try {
    $query->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. this code is valid i know. However, i am looking for a script that, when i changed with old code works same. because the rest of the code is really long and if i change alot, i will have to change all

Comment: So you're confident that the query is executing fine?

Comment: @RubyMewMew It should be `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` to match the original code.

Comment: Sidenote: During development (only), it's better to use `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Doing just a `catch(PDOException $e)` isn't always enough.