# What is the exact equivalent of mysqli_fetch_array function in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

Since i've changed to PDO, i really can't seem to get the right function to use that would do exactly what mysqli_fetch_array() was doing, this happens probably because i don't realy understand the real diffrence between mysqli_fetch_array and PDO's fecth().

From some sources, while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) "fetches a single row from the resultset each time it is called.", whereas $row = $query->fetch() is returning the whole resultset in one single call.

I've asked two similar questions and one with a bounty but i can't seem to get a proper way around what i want to do.

, [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575895/translation-mysql-fetch-array-to-pdofetch-num),

- mysql_fetch_array = fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) - The rows are arrays with both numeric and   named indexes.
- mysql_fetch_assoc = fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) - The rows are arrays with named indexes.
- mysql_fetch_row = fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) - The rows are arrays with numeric indexes.
- mysql_fetch_object = fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS) depending on whether you specify the optional className argument to mysql_fetch_object. The rows are objects, either of the specified class or stdClass.
- The while loop is equivalent to:

$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH),

Using the first on this list just seems to behave differently from what mysqli_fetch_arrray does.

What i've tried returns so many errors in the while loop and crushes the browser at times, thanks to Chrome, i won't post that.

**HERE's what i want to do**.

```
$counter = 0;    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $counter++;
    echo $counter;
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

If we have three rows: **RESULT**;

```
1
TRIQUESHA

2
STACEY

3
DAQUEN
```

**NOW PDO**

```
$count = 0;
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
$counter++;
    echo $counter;
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

Again if we have three rows: **PDO RESULT**;

```
3
TRIQUESHA

3
STACEY

3
DAQUEN
```

It's not counting, its returning the total number of rows instead, if i had 50 rows, it would repeat 50 on each row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the question about the 3's being repeated?

Comment: It's not counting, its returning the total number of rows instead, if i had 50 rows, it would repeat 50 on each row.

Comment: `$count` and `$counter` are **different** variables.

Comment: That's a typo when i was reproducing the code here.

Comment: You still missed one instance of it.

Comment: We'd need to see your queries and how are you executing them. And please take a moment to reproduce your code here like it actually is, if it has typos it wont really get you any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $count and $counter are different variables. –  hjpotter92
>
> That's a typo when i was reproducing the code here. –  user3109875

That very typo is the real problem here. You are seeing 3 in PDO version being repeated cause its your `$counter` variable set to 3 after your mysqli loop, and it never gets updated. You need to reset it correctly before the PDO loop to see.

```
//$count = 0;   // Wrong
$counter=0;    //  Correct. 
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    $counter++; 
    echo $counter;
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

**Edit:**

While Mark M correctly pointed out what I overlooked, I still believe that is the cause of this error. See this revision in that question's edit history

```
$count = 0;
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
$count++;
    echo $counter;    //This will always remain 3 because you are incrementing $count
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

This will exactly cause the behavior that this answer suggests. Now if that is the actual code then that's the actual reason, if that's different from what it really is, then this answer is invalid.

Comment: Even if not reset to 0, it would still change each time by `$counter++`