# Return array results from db PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Apologies for opening what should be considered a very basic question. Please note I have coded using the `mysql_query` method 1000's of times thus, it is really difficult for me to make the switch but I'm finally doing it.

**My 1st Problem**

My 1st problem comes in simply returning a list of select statements

Example:I am trying to execute:

```
$sql="Select *From members";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $name = $row['name'];
}
```

I have read the following SO questions, and tried to implement the answers without success,

[PDO equivalent of mysql_fetch_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142444/pdo-equivalent-of-mysql-fetch-array)

[translation mysql_fetch_array to PDO::FETCH_NUM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575895/translation-mysql-fetch-array-to-pdofetch-num)

I am now working with a **PHP book supposed to be "one of the best for 2015/16"**, *the book says the following regarding the above problem*

[image]

Again I have tried the recommendation from the book without success

```
<?php
$dsn ='mysql:localhost;dbname:myDB;';
$uname = 'root';
$pword = '';
$db = new PDO($dsn, $uname,$pword);
if($db){
  echo'Success';    
} else {
  echo'error';  
} 

$sql="SELECT * from members";
$results = $db->query($sql);
foreach($results as $result) {
  echo $result['name'];
}
```

The above code gives me the message, "success" thus, I am successfully connecting to my DB but the query returns the following error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I am finding it enormously frustrating that I have to go through such lengths just to return the results from a simple `select` statement and am seriously considering going back to the old way, where I would have completed my assignment by now, I am turning to the SO community for help in a last attempt to get it right. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `PDO::query` returns a [PDOStatement object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) which you can use to `fetch` results.

Comment: @apokryfos OK but why does my $50 book give me a different example...just asking?

Comment: `PDOStatement implements Traversable` which means you can iterate it via a foreach, provided the query worked.

Comment: Are you sure your query is actually returning successfully? Put a `print_r($db->errorInfo());` before the `foreach` and after the `query` to make sure.

Comment: If you're told that your argument to `foreach` is incorrect, then **inspect what argument you're actually giving to `foreach`.**

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Because it is a book and books are evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very ashamed of posting this, but I have found the problem. Possibly it might help someone in the future.

The code with querying the DB is fine.

The Problem is with the following in line 1:

```
$dsn ='mysql:localhost;dbname:myDB;';
```

It should read

```
$dsn ='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB;';
```

The `If` statment will always return `echo success` even if you are not connected thus, use `try/catch`

**lesson learned:** *Always inspect your code from line 1*

Comment: Additionally, second lesson to learn: don't trust simple `if($db) {...}` validation checks. ;)

Comment: indeed - dont take shortcuts

Comment: It's curious that `new PDO` didn't result in an uncaught exception which killed the entire program... 

Comment: Well at least I spotted it eventually

Comment: An exception will be thrown eventually when you try to query the database with a "No database selected" exception, etc

Comment: @deceze looks like it's a bug in PDO.